# Javascript button with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT:

Currently using this javascript code, it works for the plus box but not the minus. (changed code fragment from the below.

```javascript
// Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
newAddButton.id= "submit2";
newAddButton.type = "button";
newAddButton.value = " + ";


var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
newDelButton.type = "button";
newDelButton.value = " - ";
newAddButton.id= "submit2";
```

I've got a javascript form, two buttons and a form is created when the plus is clicked, I was just wondering if the buttons that appear can be set to the same CSS style as the button next to the drop down lists.

So in short a css style attached to the buttons made through a javascript

HTML

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div>
    <select name="text[]">
      <option value="t1">t1</option>
      <option value="t2">t2</option>
      <option value="t3">t3</option>
    </select>
    <input name="none" type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();" value=" + ">
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```javascript
var counter = 0;

function addNew(e) {

  var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

  var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

  var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

  // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');

  // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

  // Create a new text input

  var newText = document.createElement('select');
  newText.type = "select"; 
  newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

  newText.innerHTML = items;

  //for testing

  // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
  var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
  newAddButton.type = "button";
  newAddButton.value = " + ";

  var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
  newDelButton.type = "button";
  newDelButton.value = " - ";

  // Append new text input to the newDiv
  newDiv.appendChild(newText);

  // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
  newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);
  newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);

  // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
  mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

  // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
  newAddButton.onclick = addNew;

  newDelButton.onclick = function() {
    mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
  };
};
```

Comment: The type of an input is "submit", not "button".

Comment: Please post relative HTML & CSS or make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @bvx89 button input types: `button`, `submit`, `reset`.

Comment: hi yes, here is the fiddle, for some reason the button doesnt work on there but it does normally. if you look at the javascript i need to make the + and - button have the ID as submit 2   http://jsfiddle.net/AMant21/Ha3d6/

Comment: @user2999825 IDs have to be unique. Change to classes if you need multiple items with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with the fiddle.

1. To get your question out of the way, the CSS has an extraneous `}`, which causes the style for `#submit3` to be ignored. Remove it.
2. The Javascript in the fiddle should not be wrapped in an onload handler; set it to "No wrap - in head" or "No wrap - in body". Otherwise clicking the button won't work.
3. The newly created buttons all have the same IDS. This is a no-no. Make the Javascript remember how many buttons there are and give them a unique ID based on the count. (Something like `++numberofbuttons; id = 'submit'+(numberofbuttons*2);` for the one, and same plus `+1` for the other.)
4. Oh, and your fiddle differs from the example code in the question. Don't do that.